# How do I prevent an application from opening a web browser in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-association

Is there a way to disable this security vulnerability?

Absolutely any application seems capable of opening Edge to any web page it likes without prompting the user.

Comment: Just make notepad.exe (or whatever) your default browser

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 may let you set Notepad as default, will try it.

Comment: Seems to be working, need to test things further to make sure I'm not opening up any new vulnerabilities.

Comment: Why is starting an executable a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent an application from launching another application.  The application inherits the users permissions that ran the application.  If that user has access to another application (ie, Edge), then that app has access.

You can run the application as another user, in which you can deny access to the internet or the folder containing the application.  Depending on how the app was coded, this will work fine.  At worst, it could cause the application to crash.

Comment: Seems like browsers should prompt for a url issued as a command line argument...  Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the Registry.

Goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet` and replace the default browser that appears listed there with something null or with any non-dangerous custom Application (notepad, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd tried setting it to a custom application, however the application I'm running still opens pages in Edge.  I believe I need to rephrase my question.